# Connection to Read-only embedded SQL Server compact edition (.sdf file) in WPF application

Tags: sql-server-ce, database-connection, wpfdatagrid

I am looking for a solution to the following:

**Find a properly formatted connection string to SQL server compact edition file (.sdf) used as embedded resource, containing reference (i.e. read-only) data in WPF application.**

*Note: please pay attention to the operative words [**Build Action**] set to "**Embedded Resource**" and "**Do Not Copy**" to the output directory settings. It means that the file will not be physically copied to the target computer as a stand-alone entity, but instead is embedded in app executable.*

So far I have tested a solution that allows getting the .sdf file from embedded resource with simple code snippet (Listing 1):

**Listing 1.**

```
    Assembly _execAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    // helper snippet to find out all available embedded resource names
    string[] _resources = _execAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

    //.sdf included in IO.Stream

    System.IO.Stream _stream 
= Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyAssemblyName.App_Data.MyDB.sdf");
```

... need the rest of the code to convert _`stream` object to .sdf and to connect to this file using either `DataSet/TableAdapter`, or `System.Data.SqlServerCe` objects; `SqlCeConnection`, `SqlCeCommand`, `SqlCeDataReader` as shown in the following sample code snippet (Listing 2):

**Listing 2.**

```
#region private: Get DataTable using SqlCeDataReader
/// <summary>
/// Get DataTable using SqlCeDataReader
/// </summary>
/// <param name="strConn">string</param>
/// <param name="strSQL">string</param>
/// <returns>DataTable</returns>
private static DataTable GetDataTableFromFileCeReader(string strConn, string strSQL)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlCeConnection _connSqlCe = new SqlCeConnection(strConn))
        {
            using (SqlCeCommand _commandSqlCe = new SqlCeCommand())
            {
                _commandSqlCe.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                _commandSqlCe.Connection = _connSqlCe;
                _commandSqlCe.CommandText = strSQL;
                _connSqlCe.Open();

                using (SqlCeDataReader _drSqlCe = _commandSqlCe.ExecuteReader()) {
                    DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
                    _dt.Load(_drSqlCe);
                    _connSqlCe.Close();
                    return _dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
#endregion
```

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I use in my SQL Server Compact Toolbox:

```
private static string CreateStore()
    {
        var factory = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(Resources.SqlCompact35InvariantName);
        string fileName = GetSdfName();
        string connString = string.Format("Data Source={0};", fileName);
        bool created = false;
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Resources.SqlCe35AddinStore))
            {
                // Create a FileStream object to write a stream to a file 
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(fileName, (int)stream.Length))
                {
                    // Fill the bytes[] array with the stream data 
                    byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[stream.Length];
                    stream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);
                    // Use FileStream object to write to the specified file 
                    fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
                    created = true;
                }
            }
        }

        using (var conn = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            if (created)
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = connString;
                conn.Open();
                using (var cmd = factory.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Databases (Id INT IDENTITY, Source nvarchar(2048) NOT NULL, FileName nvarchar(512) NOT NULL, CeVersion int NOT NULL)";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        return connString;
    }

    private static string GetSdfName()
    {
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "SqlCe35AddinStore.sdf");
        return fileName;
    }
```

Comment: Erik, thanks a bunch for your prompt response. Looking at your code, it seems like the .sdf file will be created from stream and put in the LocalApplicationData folder on the target computer. In   a specific requirement I wrote that .sdf file SHOULD NOT appear anywhere on the User's PC; it should stay embedded in .exe for all time. In other words, it should be consumed as in-memory DB, not as a physical file on User's PC (note: this is a read-only file as stated in my post). Kind regards,

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood - That requirement cannot be fulfilled by SQL Server Compact, it requires the presence of a file in the file system.

Comment: Thanks, anyway! I appreciate your kind attention. Btw, using your suggested technique it's theoretically possible to create a temp file just for a short period of time, which is necessary to load all of its DataTable in-memory, and immediately after that to delete the file. This solution is far from perfect as it adds huge overhead to data operations. It would be much better if Microsoft folks provide some sort of API allowing direct access to embedded (in-memory) compact SQL data resources, i.e. not using any external file operations. Kind regards,

Comment: FWIW, SQlite allows you to place a database entirely in memory. But you would need to fill it with data from somewhere.

Comment: Thanks again, Erik, I will definitely look at SQLite option. Any practical SQLite-based solution will be appreciated, i.e. an example of simple single-table DB embedded in WPF .exe and related procedure (in C#) to get its content into standard DataTable object. Kind regards,

Comment: ErikEJ, I accept your solution: with a bit of modification I was able to achieve what I was looking for. The last question: should I also copy all that 7 DLLs to app dir or just a single one: System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll? In case all that 7 are necessary, then is it possible to convert them into a single assembly? Many thanks,

Comment: You may only need the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll and ..qp ..me ..se and ..er40. And since they are unmanaged, no, no singel assembly.