# Combining Values in a DataView

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to wpf.
I tried searching for answers but it's hard to describe what I'm trying to do.

Suppose I have a DataView which contains the following:

```
Label  | Number
----------------
Apple  |  1
Orange |  5
Apple  |  2
Orange | 10
```

What would be the best way to "condense" this information?
What I mean is for the end result to look like this in a ListView + GridView?

```
Label  | Number
----------------
Apple  |  3
Orange | 15
```

The data that I'm trying to condense is coming from an Access Database. This is being read through a table adapter/data set in Visual Studio. The table adapter fills a table of the dataset, and then I create a custom view out of that dataset table.

```
DBDataSet ds = new DBDataSet ();
DBDataSetTableAdapters.TableNameAdapter adapter = new DBDataSetTableAdapters.TableNameAdapter();

adapter.Fill(ds.TableName);
DataView view = ds.TableName.DefaultView;
view.RowFilter = "[Label] = 'Apple' OR [Label] = 'Orange'";
```

Apologies, I've written this almost entirely from memory.

Comment: Could you post your data classes, so we can create a sample for you. also xaml data template would be nice to have.

Answer (score 1):

Yo have to use an aggregate query, i.e. Group By

```
string _sql ="Select Label, Sum(Number) As Tot FROM [TableName] Group By Label";
```

and pass it to the connection object - take a look at the example I've posted:
[Connection to Read-only embedded SQL Server compact edition (.sdf file) in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328784/connection-to-read-only-embedded-sql-server-compact-edition-sdf-file-in-wpf-a) (note: instead of SqlCe data objects you should use OleDb to work w/Access mdb). You will need this part to get DataTable:

```
#region private: Get DataTable using SqlCeDataReader
/// <summary>
/// Get DataTable using SqlCeDataReader
/// </summary>
/// <param name="strConn">string</param>
/// <param name="strSQL">string</param>
/// <returns>DataTable</returns>
private static DataTable GetDataTableFromFileCeReader(string strConn, string strSQL)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlCeConnection _connSqlCe = new SqlCeConnection(strConn))
        {
            using (SqlCeCommand _commandSqlCe = new SqlCeCommand())
            {
                _commandSqlCe.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                _commandSqlCe.Connection = _connSqlCe;
                _commandSqlCe.CommandText = strSQL;
                _connSqlCe.Open();

                using (SqlCeDataReader _drSqlCe = _commandSqlCe.ExecuteReader()) {
                    DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
                    _dt.Load(_drSqlCe);
                    _connSqlCe.Close();
                    return _dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
#endregion
```

Then use `DefaultView` property on that DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some data where you can not aggregate in SQL you can use the following sample for same result

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Label", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Apple", 1 });
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Apple", 2 });
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Orange", 5 });
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Orange", 10 });

    var CombinedView = from rowGroup in table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Label"))
                       select new { Label = rowGroup.Key, Number = rowGroup.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Number")) };
```

or

```
    var CombinedView = from row in table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                       group row.Field<int>("Number") by row.Field<string>("Label") into rowGroup
                       select new { Label = rowGroup.Key, Number = rowGroup.Sum() };
```

Idea is to group rows by the Label column and sum the values within that group.

now you can bind it to a data grid or any item control of your choice

eg

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CombinedView}" />
```

result

[image: result]